# Elastic painless 'state' alternative

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

This is my first attempt at a painless script, however almost every example makes use of a 'state' object which is not available in my version.

i.e.

```
"aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.id_map = [:]; state.sum = 0.0;",
        "map_script": """
          def id = doc['record_id.ID'].value;
          if (!state.id_map.containsKey(id)) {
            state.id_map[id] = true;
            state.sum += doc['VAL'].value;
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
            def sum = state.sum;
            def stats = [:];
            stats.sum = sum;
            return stats
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
```

Result in : Variable [state] is not defined.

Omitting it doesn't help either
i.e.

```
"init_script": "Map id_map = new HashMap(); double sum = 0.0;",
        "map_script": """
          def id = doc['record_id.ID'].value;
          if (!id_map.containsKey(id)) {
            id_map[id] = true;
            sum += doc['VAL'].value;
          }
        """,
```

Results in:
"Variable [id_map] is not defined." in the map_script section

What's the alternative approach for earlier versions ?

Comment: `init_script` is only used in `scripted_metric` aggregation, is this what you're trying to do? Can you share some more context?

Comment: Hi thanks for reading - I am trying to perform a sum aggregation while removing duplicates (based on an identifier field). Edited the initial code to show the scripted_metric outer clause now.

Comment: Which version of ES are you running? I'm tested on 7.9.2 and your script works just fine

Comment: All I really know is it's some 5.x version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts you have above work fine in version 6.4 onwards.

Since you're running ES 5.x you need to [change a little bit the syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html):

- replace `state` by `params._agg`
- replace `states` by `params._aggs`

Like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "params._agg.id_map = [:]; params._agg.sum = 0.0;",
        "map_script": """
          def id = doc['record_id.ID'].value;
          if (!params._agg.id_map.containsKey(id)) {
            params._agg.id_map[id] = true;
            params._agg.sum += doc['VAL'].value;
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": """
            def sum = params._agg.sum;
            def stats = [:];
            stats.sum = sum;
            return stats
        """,
        "reduce_script": "return params._aggs"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: amazing, thank you this works! Quick follow up if you don't mind. It's always returning 5 sum results, whereas I know there are 133 distinct ID's. (it seems to be doing one sum per 'shard' instead of per ID I think)